# Unnecessary language packs installed during setup

Tags: system-installation

I noticed a significant amount of install time was consumed downloading many language packs. Later during the installation, most of the packs were removed.
My question is why, when I have selected my language and location, is it necessary to install what seems like every other language in the world, increasing download data and time significantly. And then, even worse spend more time removing the unnecessary ones?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been addressed at least [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9qv0s6/why_does_the_ubuntu_installer_delete_packages/e8cnoj1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

> The disk image approach not only allows the "try Ubuntu" feature but it is also faster to copy the image and uninstall the parts that aren't needed than to install over 1000 packages.

[The person](https://launchpad.net/~jbicha) who posted that is quite involved in Ubuntu matters and has an [Ask Ubuntu account](https://askubuntu.com/users/1579/jeremy-bicha) as well.

The reason given also may explain why, when we choose a minimal install option, all packages are *first* installed and *then* packages like LibreOffice, etc are removed.